# Adding a ContextListener to a full java based Spring configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring, web, configuration

I'm trying to set up a Spring configuration based on Java `@Configuration` class and `web.xml` file.
I have defined two different configurations: `KatherineConfig.java` that holds the configuration of JPA layer; `KatherineWebConfig.java` that imports the first configuration file and adds servlet mapping to Spring configuration.

Now I would like to add a `ContextLoaderListener` to my configuration. I have no idea on how to do it.

This is my web.xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.3"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_3.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>it.manuelgozzi.katherine.web.configuration.KatherineWebConfig
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <display-name>Katherine</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is my `KatherineWebConfig.java` file:

```
package it.manuelgozzi.katherine.web.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import it.manuelgozzi.katherine.finance.configuration.KatherineConfig;

@Configuration
@Import(KatherineConfig.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "it.manuelgozzi.katherine.web" })
@EnableWebMvc
public class KatherineWebConfig {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

And finally this is `KatherineConfig.java` file:

```
package it.manuelgozzi.katherine.finance.configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

/**
 * Configurazione di Katherine. I parametri sono gestiti esternamente mediante
 * il file katherine.configuration.properties.
 * 
 * @author Manuel Gozzi
 * @date Jan 6, 2019
 * @time 6:12:48 PM
 */
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"it.manuelgozzi.katherine.finance", "it.manuelgozzi.katherine.web"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "it.manuelgozzi.katherine.finance.model.entity.repository")
@PropertySource("classpath:katherine.configuration.properties")
public class KatherineConfig {

    @Value("${datasource.username}")
    private String dataSourceUsername;

    @Value("${datasource.password}")
    private String dataSourcePassword;

    @Value("${datasource.url}")
    private String dataSourceUrl;

    @Value("${datasource.driverclassname}")
    private String dataSourceDriverClassName;

    @Value("${entitymanager.packagestoscan}")
    private String entityManagerPackagesToScan;

    /**
     * Configurazione del bean relativo al datasource.
     * 
     * @author Manuel Gozzi
     * @date Jan 6, 2019
     * @time 6:13:01 PM
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUsername(dataSourceUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(dataSourcePassword);
        dataSource.setUrl(dataSourceUrl);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(dataSourceDriverClassName);
        return dataSource;
    }

    /**
     * Configurazione del TransactionManager.
     * 
     * @author Manuel Gozzi
     * @date Jan 6, 2019
     * @time 6:13:12 PM
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    /**
     * Configurazione dell'EntityManagerFactory.
     * 
     * @author Manuel Gozzi
     * @date Jan 6, 2019
     * @time 6:13:24 PM
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { entityManagerPackagesToScan });
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        return em;
    }

}
```

Could you kindly explain me how to implement this solution?
My goal is to stand up with Java configuration and `web.xml` together.

I am trying to run my application as it is but I'm getting the following Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
```

Thanks in advice!

**EDIT:**

I have created a class that implements `WebApplicationInitializer` in this way:

```
package it.manuelgozzi.katherine.web.configuration;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;

import it.manuelgozzi.katherine.finance.configuration.KatherineConfig;

public class KatherineWebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext annotationConfigContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        annotationConfigContext.register(KatherineWebConfig.class);
        annotationConfigContext.register(KatherineConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(annotationConfigContext));
    }

}
```

Now I'm getting the following Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ResourceLoader must not be null!
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your configuration class [AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.html):

```
 context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
 context.register(KatherineConfig.class);
```

> WebApplicationContext implementation which accepts annotated classes as input - in particular @Configuration-annotated classes

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. How could I do that? Do I have to create a new class that implements WebApplicationInitializer and do an @Override of "onStartup" method? If yes, once done, how can I tell to Spring to load that one? I'm confused a bit.

Comment: @ManuelGozzi Spring will find this class on startup

Comment: I've added an EDIT, please check it.

Comment: @ManuelGozzi your web.xml `<web-app` tag should use version `3.0`

Comment: the issue is still here. I updated my web.xml file with 3.0 version as suggested.